# PIVOT using JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot

I was asked to pivot this data using basic SQL and wasn't sure how to answer it. I googled some answers and realized you can use MAX or SUM with CASE expressions, but at the end of the interview I asked how you would solve the question and the interviewer said by using joins. Can anyone show me how it's done using joins?

**BEGINNING TABLE**

| emp_id | col_id | col_desc | attvalue | month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | salary | 2000 | 2010-05-09 |
| 1 | 2 | bonus | 0 | 2010-05-09 |
| 1 | 3 | compensation | 2000 | 2010-05-09 |
| 1 | 1 | salary | 2000 | 2010-05-10 |
| 1 | 2 | bonus | 500 | 2010-05-10 |
| 1 | 3 | compensation | 2500 | 2010-05-10 |
| 2 | 1 | salary | 1000 | 2010-05-09 |
| 2 | 2 | bonus | 500 | 2010-05-09 |
| 2 | 3 | compensation | 1500 | 2010-05-09 |

Code to create the beginning table

```
CREATE TABLE Employees(emp_id INT, col_id INT, col_desc NVARCHAR(MAX), attvalue INT, month DATE);

INSERT INTO Employees
VALUES
(1,1,'salary',2000,'2010-05-09'),
(1,2,'bonus',0,'2010-05-09'),
(1,3,'compensation',2000,'2010-05-09'),
(1,1,'salary',2000,'2010-05-10'),
(1,2,'bonus',500,'2010-05-10'),
(1,3,'compensation',2500,'2010-05-10'),
(2,1,'salary',1000,'2010-05-09'),
(2,2,'bonus',500,'2010-05-09'),
(2,3,'compensation',1500,'2010-05-09');
```

**RESULTING TABLE**

| emp_id | month | salary | bonus | compensation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010-05-09 | 2000 | 0 | 2000 |
| 1 | 2010-05-10 | 2000 | 500 | 2500 |
| 2 | 2010-05-09 | 1000 | 500 | 1500 |

Comment: `self join` is just one way. You can also use the `case` expression or `pivot` operator

Comment: @Squirrel yeah I answered the question using `pivot` but that wasn't "correct" in the eye of the interviewer he wanted a way without using `pivot`. I figured out how to do it with `case` expression, but I still haven't been able to figure it out using `self join`, I was hoping someone could show me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the self join, case expression and pivot way

```
-- Self Join way
select s.emp_id, s.month, 
       s.attvalue as salary,
       b.attvalue as bonus,
       c.attvalue as compensation
from   Employees s
       inner join Employees b on  s.emp_id   = b.emp_id
                             and  s.month    = b.month
       inner join Employees c on  s.emp_id   = c.emp_id
                             and  s.month    = c.month
where  s.col_desc = 'salary'
and    b.col_desc = 'bonus'
and    c.col_desc = 'compensation'
order by s.emp_id, s.month

-- case expression way
select emp_id, month,
       max(case when col_desc = 'salary' then attvalue else 0 end) as salary,
       max(case when col_desc = 'bonus'  then attvalue else 0 end) as bonus,
       max(case when col_desc = 'compensation' then attvalue else 0 end) as compensation
from   Employees
group by emp_id, month
order by emp_id, month

-- Pivot way
select *
from   (
           select emp_id, month, col_desc, attvalue
           from Employees
       ) d
       pivot
       (
           max(attvalue)
           for col_desc in ([salary], [bonus], [compensation])
       ) p
order by emp_id, month
```

Comment: THANK YOU! this has been really helpful. Which way would be the most efficient?

Comment: Nice one @Squirrell

Comment: @biguzs you can't determine a queries performance based on the query alone, it depends on table structure, indexes, query plans etc. You need to try them and see. The general advice when writing a SQL query is to write it in the manner which makes the most logical sense to you, and only worry about performance if performance actually becomes an issue. There are a few performance guidelines, such as avoid scalar functions and cursors etc, but there are no hard and fast rules in SQL - its nearly always try it and see.